# PHP foreach loop through multidimensional array

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I have an multidimensional array, how can I use it? I want to use each separate array in a `for` loop.

What I want to achive is to be able to put each part in my database like
entry in db no. 0 -> 1 and 4
entry in db no. 1 -> 5 and 6
entry in db no. 2 -> 1 and 4 and 5 and 6

I have this code:

```
<?php 
    print_r($calculatie_id); 
    for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) 
{ 
?>  
<tr> 
    <td> 

    <?php 
    foreach ($calculatie_id[$i] as $value) 
    { 
        echo $value; 
    } 
?>

print_r($calculatie_id); gives 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 ) [3] => )
```

But when using the `foreach` I only get 46

Some extra information:

This array is created by an multiple select in an for loop. Any other suggestions are welcome.

```
    for ($i=0; $i<=$aantal_regels_corr; $i++)
{ 
?> 
<tr>
    <td>

        <?php 
        // maak select name
        $calculatie_id = 'calculatie_id'.$i;

        // rest van formulier
        if($error_vergeten[$i] == "ja"){ $error_omschr = $error_omschr_vergeten[$i]; include('includes/input_error.php'); } ?>&nbsp;<textarea rows="7" cols="80" name="omschrijving[]" /><?php echo $omschrijving[$i]; ?></textarea>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <select multiple="multiple" width="50" size="7" name="<?php echo $calculatie_id ?>[]" style="width: 150px">
        <?php
            $sql_calc = "select id, naam, actief from sp_calculatie WHERE (offerte_id = '".$row['off_offerte']."' OR offerte_id = '".$offerte_id."') AND actief = 'ja' ORDER BY id ASC";
            $res_calc = mysql_query($sql_calc,$con);  
            while ($row_calc = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_calc)){
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_calc["id"] ?>"><?php if (empty($row_calc["naam"])) { echo $row_calc["id"]; } else { echo $row_calc["naam"]; } ?></option>
        <?php } ?></select>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach($calculatie_id as $inner_arr)
    foreach($inner_arr as $value)
        echo $value;
```

**Edit:** you should try to learn and understand what's going on here. Then, you can do whatever you want with the code I wrote. You said: *gives 14561456 I want to use `$calculatie_id0=14 $calculatie_id1=56 $calculatie_id2=1456` etc* Then, you will have to do something like this:

```
foreach($calculatie_id as $index => $inner_arr){
    echo "$calculatie_id$index = "
    foreach($inner_arr as $value)
        echo $value;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Or you can create those variables you want (which does not make any sense for me):

```
foreach($calculatie_id as $index => $inner_arr){
    ${"calculatie_id$index"} = '';
    foreach($inner_arr as $value)
        ${"calculatie_id$index"} .= $value;
    echo ${"calculatie_id$index"}."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 ) [3] => ) 

gives

14561456

I want to use
$calculatie_id0=14
$calculatie_id1=56
$calculatie_id2=1456
etc.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you have is an array like this:

```
array(
 array(
  data
 )
)
```

All you need is:

```
foreach($yourArray as $innerArray)
 foreach($innerArray as $value)
  echo $value;
```

That will output what you want. I'm not particularly sure why you're doing a for() loop then a foreach.

Comment: I have added more info to the opening post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your `foreach` loops (so you have a loop inside a loop)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
foreach ($calculatie_id as $key => $value) {
  echo "$calculatie_id:".$key;
  for ($i=0;$i<=count($value);$i++) {
    echo $value[$i];
  }
}
```

Comment: thx but this is the result:

Array:014Array:156Array:21456Array:3

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your original code snippet isn't working. Could it be the fact that `$calculatie_id[3]` is not an array?

I tried this:

```
<?php

$calculatie_id = array ( array(4,6), array(1,5), array(5,6), '' );

for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) 
{ 
  if(!is_array($calculatie_id[$i]))
    continue;
  echo "$i: ";
  foreach ($calculatie_id[$i] as $value) 
  { 
    echo $value; 
  } 
  echo '<br/>';
}
```

And that prints:

> 0: 46
>   1: 15
>   2: 56

Comment: How to prevent tat is uses an array that doesn't exists?

Comment: @Muiter: well like i said, you can use `if(!is_array($calculatie_id[$i])) continue;` to go on to the next iteration of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for helping me out this far but all the examples I try to implement are not working.
I have been trying this script for over 2 weeks now. It seems I'm going all the wrong way.

I have put my code online at www.pws.nl/downloads/sp_offerte_add.rar. It must be easier then what I'm writing in the code right now.